# How to change one image to another image with setState

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a GridView Component in react native. And I have two different icons to highlight the grid image.

Here how can I change the icons while onPress the image with setState.

```
<GridView
        itemDimension={80}
        items={items}
        style={styles.gridView}
        renderItem={({ item }) => this.renderGrid(item)}
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this approach:

1. Initialize a state(Array) in which you will store currently selected images

   e.g.

   ```
   this.state = {
     selectedImages: []
   }
   ```
2. Whenever someone clicks on an image you have to push or pop the image's id(or some unique key) into `selecetedImages` state. This can be done in `onPress` of images. Whenever `onPress` run first check if array contains current image's id(or some unique key) then splice the id else push into `selectedImages` array
3. To show the highlight icon you can do something like that

   ```
   {selectedImages.includes(image.id) ? <HighlightIcon /> : null}
   ```

Hope this helps you